# javascript forEach loop to add two separate active classes on click and remove previously selected active classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach

```js
// --Catering Container--
//On click add active class to selected button
let btnContainer = document.querySelector('.sliderContainers');
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderContainers__sliderBtn');


btn.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btnContainer.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');

    el.classList.add('active');
  });
});
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

//Global Variables Catering Section-------------------------------------

// Buttons
let familyButton = document.getElementById('family');
let specialButton = document.getElementById('special');
let socialButton = document.getElementById('social');

// Txt content 'Family Gathering''Special Events''Social Events'
let title = document.getElementById('title');
let description = document.getElementById('description');



//Family Gathering-----------------------------------------------------
familyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Family Gathering';
  description.textContent = 'We love catering for entire families. So please bring everyone along for a special meal with your loved ones. We’ll provide a memorable experience for all.';

});

//Special Events--------------------------------------------------------
specialButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Special Events';
  description.textContent = 'Whether it’s a romantic dinner or special date you’re celebrating with others we’ll look after you. We’ll be sure to mark your special date with an unforgettable meal.';

});

//Social Events---------------------------------------------------------
socialButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Social Events';
  description.textContent = 'Are you looking to have a larger social event? No problem! We’re more than happy to cater for big parties. We’ll work with you to make your event a hit with everyone.';

});
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
.indexContainer {
  display: grid;
  background: var(--color-background-white);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 22rem) minmax(auto, 52.4rem) repeat(2, minmax(auto, 68.3rem)) minmax(auto, 179.2rem) minmax(auto, 104rem) minmax(auto, 32.8rem) minmax(auto, 44rem);
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] auto [center-start] repeat(12, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 5rem)[col-end]) [center-end] auto [full-end];
}

.cateringContainer {
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  grid-column: center-start / center-end;
  &__inner {
    &-imageDesktop {
      display: none;
    }
    &-imageTablet {
      display: none;
    }
    &-image {
      @include imageCatering();
      max-height: 40rem;
    }
  }
}

.sliderContainers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 11.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  order: 1;
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cateringLine {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 7rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  background: var(--color-lines-beaver);
}

.cateringLine.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.headingXlrgBold {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
}

.headingLrg {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.225px;
  color: #111111;
}

.headingMedium {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  // opacity: 0.5;
}

//Summary's
.summary {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1875px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-text-ebonyClay);
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <h1 id="title" class="contentWrapper__gatheringHeading headingXlrgBold">Family Gathering</h1>
  <span id="description" class="contentWrapper__txt summary">We love catering for entire families. So please bring everyone along for a special meal with your loved ones. We’ll provide a memorable experience for all.</span>
  <button id="toBooking2" class="bookTableTxt bookTableBtnSlider" type="button">Book a table</button>
  <div class="sliderContainers">
    <button id="family" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn active headingMedium">Family Gathering
            <div class="cateringLine active"></div>
          </button>
    <button id="special" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn headingMedium">Special Events
            <div class="cateringLine"></div>
          </button>
    <button id="social" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn  headingMedium">Social Events
            <div class="cateringLine"></div>
          </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

--Overview of the HTML--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have 3 buttons two of which have a class "sliderContainers__sliderBtn" and the first one with the active class enabled initially like so "sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active" - initially. All 3 buttons in one div wrapper, class of "sliderContainers". Each button is a wrapper as-well inside is a div with a class "cateringLine", with one button out of the three having the active class enabled initially just like the button does..."cateringLine.active"

--What i am trying to accomplish---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I want on the click of each button "sliderContainers__sliderBtn" to apply the "active" class on the button as-well as on the div inside the button "cateringLine", At the same time removing the active class from the previously selected button -- 3 buttons one active at a time, 3 divs inside the buttons one active at a time.

--What the active class does------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"active" should apply an opacity of 1 to the button element as-well as apply an opacity of 1 to the "cateringLine" div.

--This is what ive come up with to add the active class onto the button which seems to be working... On click its adding the active class to the selected ".sliderContainers__sliderBtn" while removing the active on the previously selected button. Im not sure how to add the div with the class ".cateringLine" in with this though to add the active class on the catering line at the same time as the button while removing the previous ".cateringLine" active class. Does this need to be a separate forEach loop or can it be inside the same one as the button? Ive tried putting it in with the same forEach loop used for the button but i'm doing something wrong because i can only get the line to show initially and then it removes the active class on click of another button but doesn't apply the active class to the new button clicked.

---

```
<div class="sliderContainers">
  <button id="family" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn active headingMedium">Family Gathering
    <div class="cateringLine active"></div>
  </button>
  <button id="special" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn headingMedium">Special Events
    <div class="cateringLine"></div>
  </button>
  <button id="social" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn  headingMedium">Social Events
    <div class="cateringLine"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

---

//On click add active class to selected button

```
let btnContainer = document.querySelector('.sliderContainers');
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderContainers__sliderBtn'); 


btn.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        btnContainer.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        
        el.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

-- The button

```
.sliderContainers__sliderBtn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

-- Div inside the button

```
.cateringLine {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 7rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    background: var(--color-lines-beaver);
}

.cateringLine.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: you could also change your css to this: ` .sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active > .cateringLine { opacity:1; }` then you wouldn't have to change the class of the inner div keeping the javascript simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move the `cateringLine` active style definition into `sliderContainers__sliderBtn` active definition as shown below. This way the effect will happen when parent becomes active.

```
.sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active {
  opacity: 1;
  .cateringLine {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

---

If you really need to add the classes via JS for some reason, you can do it as shown below:

```
btns.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
    el.querySelector('.cateringLine').classList.add('active')
  });
});
```

```js
// --Catering Container--
//On click add active class to selected button
let btnContainer = document.querySelector('.sliderContainers');
let btns = btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.sliderContainers__sliderBtn');


btns.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btnContainer.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
    el.querySelector('.cateringLine').classList.add('active')
  });
});
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

//Global Variables Catering Section-------------------------------------

// Buttons
let familyButton = document.getElementById('family');
let specialButton = document.getElementById('special');
let socialButton = document.getElementById('social');

// Txt content 'Family Gathering''Special Events''Social Events'
let title = document.getElementById('title');
let description = document.getElementById('description');



//Family Gathering-----------------------------------------------------
familyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Family Gathering';
  description.textContent = 'We love catering for entire families. So please bring everyone along for a special meal with your loved ones. We’ll provide a memorable experience for all.';

});

//Special Events--------------------------------------------------------
specialButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Special Events';
  description.textContent = 'Whether it’s a romantic dinner or special date you’re celebrating with others we’ll look after you. We’ll be sure to mark your special date with an unforgettable meal.';

});

//Social Events---------------------------------------------------------
socialButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  title.textContent = 'Social Events';
  description.textContent = 'Are you looking to have a larger social event? No problem! We’re more than happy to cater for big parties. We’ll work with you to make your event a hit with everyone.';

});
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
.indexContainer {
  display: grid;
  background: var(--color-background-white);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 22rem) minmax(auto, 52.4rem) repeat(2, minmax(auto, 68.3rem)) minmax(auto, 179.2rem) minmax(auto, 104rem) minmax(auto, 32.8rem) minmax(auto, 44rem);
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] auto [center-start] repeat(12, [col-start] minmax(min-content, 5rem)[col-end]) [center-end] auto [full-end];
}

.cateringContainer {
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  grid-column: center-start / center-end;
  &__inner {
    &-imageDesktop {
      display: none;
    }
    &-imageTablet {
      display: none;
    }
    &-image {
      @include imageCatering();
      max-height: 40rem;
    }
  }
}

.sliderContainers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 11.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  order: 1;
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.sliderContainers__sliderBtn.active {
  opacity: 1;
  .cateringLine {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.cateringLine {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 7rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  background: var(--color-lines-beaver);
}

.headingXlrgBold {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
}

.headingLrg {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.225px;
  color: #111111;
}

.headingMedium {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  // opacity: 0.5;
}

//Summary's
.summary {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1875px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-text-ebonyClay);
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <h1 id="title" class="contentWrapper__gatheringHeading headingXlrgBold">Family Gathering</h1>
  <span id="description" class="contentWrapper__txt summary">We love catering for entire families. So please bring everyone along for a special meal with your loved ones. We’ll provide a memorable experience for all.</span>
  <button id="toBooking2" class="bookTableTxt bookTableBtnSlider" type="button">Book a table</button>
  <div class="sliderContainers">
    <button id="family" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn active headingMedium">Family Gathering
            <div class="cateringLine active"></div>
          </button>
    <button id="special" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn headingMedium">Special Events
            <div class="cateringLine"></div>
          </button>
    <button id="social" class="sliderContainers__sliderBtn  headingMedium">Social Events
            <div class="cateringLine"></div>
          </button>
  </div>
</div>
```